Is it possible to to set headers based on the requested file's size?
I'm not sure this is even possible, however, I thought it best to ask before writing it off.
Our system uses a CDN for caching, however, try as we might to keep the size down, some files that we want to serve are larger than the cache's file-size limit. This breaks the chunked downloaders as the CDN now attempts to re-serve the file from origin, but additionally apply unwanted compression. This in turn breaks our downloader as the expected chunk size and actual size are different.
Now, I'm not looking for a way to get these files into the cache (this is financially unfeasible). We're more than happy to serve this from Origin, however we need the CDN to not transform this file on the way out. Is there a way for us (probably with map, I guess, I'm honestly not that great with NGINX configuration beyond the basics of location regex) to force the Cache-Control: no-store, no-transform for files above a certain size limit?
For further information, we are paying for the CDN at the highest tier before we get to "Contact Us" levels of pricing and I've also tried just doing it based on location regex for the files I know are going to be too large (but occasionally one slips through). I can keep using this method if I have to, but I wanted to see if there was a better alternative.
